Marmalade mess up
I messed up and added the sugar to my fruit for the marmalade I'm making, before soaking, and cooking the fruit. I'm wondering if I can continue or have I ruined it?
The recipe calls for:

14 oz of fruit
2 cups of water
2 cups of sugar

Process:

Bring the fruit & water to a boil
Cover & let soak for 24 hours.
The next day, simmer for 20 mins to an hour to reduce by half.
Add sugar and simmer again for 15 to 20 mins.
(implied or) Until thick.


What's your exact recipe? It really matters here because whether or not you drain after soaking will affect whether or not you have the correct amount of sugar, and soaking isn't a universal step.  Also how you measure the sugar with respect to the fruit is crucial - if the recipe calls for weighing the cooked fruit and calculating the sugar based on that, you've used the wrong amount.  But that might be fixable if you know exactly what you started with

Thank-you! No draining. The recipe calls for 14 oz of fruit with 2 cups of water & 2 cups of sugar. I wasn't paying attention & added it all together. Rookie mistake.

Then you're probably OK if you cook the fruit gently to start with.  But to be sure I'd have to see the full recipe, line by line, not just the ingredients list

I was supposed to bring the fruit & water to a boil, cover & let soak for 24 hours. The next day, simmer for 20 mins to an hour to reduce by half. Add sugar and simmer again for 15 to 20 mins. until thick.

Cook slowly (beware of burning it, so low heat and stir often) to reduce by half and get thick, and it should give an end result pretty much the same as if done as written.
It's likely to take longer to reduce by half without burning.
